# Error al pasar un parámetro por la url

Tags: django, django-urls

Estoy creando una función que me permita recuperar el numero de celular de un usuario a partir del username.

urls globales

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path(r'', include('nucleo.urls')),
path(r'talento_humano/', include('talento_humano.urls')),
path(r'recursos/', include('recursos.urls')),
path(r'usuarios/', include('usuarios.urls')),
```

]

urls de la app

```
from django.urls import path

from usuarios.views import SisgerecuLoginView, SisgerecuLogoutView, obtener_numero_celular

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'login/', SisgerecuLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path(r'logout/', SisgerecuLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path(r'obtener_numero_celular/<usuario>', obtener_numero_celular, name='usuario.obtener_numero_celular')
]
```

función

```
def obtener_numero_celular(request, usuario):
numero_celular_usuario = User.objects.get(username=usuario).empleado.celular
return HttpResponse("%s" % numero_celular_usuario)
```

Cuando hago el llamado a esa función recibo el siguiente mensaje
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tus URLs quedarían así:

```
from django.urls import path

from usuarios.views import SisgerecuLoginView, SisgerecuLogoutView, obtener_numero_celular

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', SisgerecuLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', SisgerecuLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('obtener_numero_celular/<str:usuario>/', obtener_numero_celular, name='usuario.obtener_numero_celular')
]
```

Tienes que definir el tipo del parámetro que le vayas a pasar por la [URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/), en este caso `str`. Además esa `r` inicial que pones no sirve para nada.